# Gregorian Calendar - Document based testing

Tags: java, testing, acceptance

After doing JUnit i am doing some document based testing that has the following items in a table

Input Variables - Expected Outcome - Actual Outcome ..... Pass or Fail ....

If i pass my method a date and a time

"01AUG07" "14:40" the method should return me a gregorian calander which it does

how can i check that it has created the correct one?

thanks

unsure which to pick as the best becuase i dont no which is - i used miks and it worked.

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `GregorianCalendar` with the expect value and compare them. I'd use `SimpleDateFormat` and the [`setTime`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29) method.

```
GregorianCalendar expected = new GregorianCalendar();
expected.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse("2007-08-01 14:40"));

SystemUnderTest subject = SystemUnderTest();

assertEquals(expected, subject.method());
```

Comment: Ah, yeah sorry. I have a static method that that simply takes a ISO 8601 formatted date as a string and returns it as a date. I will Updated the answer to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example compare the string reprensetations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd <strike>calculate the</strike> use both 'textual' and their equivalent millisecond values for my test input and compare those milliseconds as expected values with the values that I get with the `Calendar#getTimeInMillis`.